# Is there a way to perform create relational pandas dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, bitmask

I am struggling to get my pandas df into the format I require due to incorrectly populating a bit masked dataframe.

I have a number of data frames:

`plot_d1_sw1` - this is a read from a .csv

```
            timestamp  switchID    deviceID  count
0 2019-05-01 07:00:00         1  GTEC122277      1
1 2019-05-01 08:00:00         1  GTEC122277      1
3 2019-05-01 10:00:00         1  GTEC122277      3
```

`d1_sw1` - this is the last 12 hours and a conditional as to whether the data appears in `filt`

```
             timestamp    num
0  2019-05-01 12:00:00  False
1  2019-05-01 11:00:00  False
2  2019-05-01 10:00:00   True
3  2019-05-01 09:00:00  False
4  2019-05-01 08:00:00   True
5  2019-05-01 07:00:00   True
6  2019-05-01 06:00:00  False
7  2019-05-01 05:00:00  False
8  2019-05-01 04:00:00  False
9  2019-05-01 03:00:00  False
10 2019-05-01 02:00:00  False
11 2019-05-01 01:00:00  False
```

I have tried masking this and pulling through the count column into the any `True` values using the following:

```
mask_d1_sw1 = d1_sw1.num == False
d1_sw1.loc[mask_d1_sw1, column_name] = 0

i=0
for row in plot_d1_sw1.itertuples():
    mask_d1_sw1 = d1_sw1.num == True
    d1_sw1.loc[mask_d1_sw1, column_name] = plot_d1_sw1['count'].values[i]
    print(d1_sw1)
    i = i + 1
```

this gives me:

```
             timestamp  num
0  2019-05-01 12:00:00    0
1  2019-05-01 11:00:00    0
2  2019-05-01 10:00:00    3
3  2019-05-01 09:00:00    0
4  2019-05-01 08:00:00    3
5  2019-05-01 07:00:00    3
6  2019-05-01 06:00:00    0
7  2019-05-01 05:00:00    0
8  2019-05-01 04:00:00    0
9  2019-05-01 03:00:00    0
10 2019-05-01 02:00:00    0
11 2019-05-01 01:00:00    0
```

... I know that this is because I am looping through the `count` column of `plot_d1_sw1` but I cannot for the life of me work out how to logically fill this to get the outcome:

```
             timestamp  num
0  2019-05-01 12:00:00    0
1  2019-05-01 11:00:00    0
2  2019-05-01 10:00:00    3
3  2019-05-01 09:00:00    0
4  2019-05-01 08:00:00    1
5  2019-05-01 07:00:00    1
6  2019-05-01 06:00:00    0
7  2019-05-01 05:00:00    0
8  2019-05-01 04:00:00    0
9  2019-05-01 03:00:00    0
10 2019-05-01 02:00:00    0
11 2019-05-01 01:00:00    0
```

How can I achieve this outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on the timestamp and then multiply the boolean values with `count`:

```
df = d1_sw1.merge(plot_d1_sw1, how='left', on='timestamp')
df['num'] = df.num.mul(df['count'].fillna(0)).astype(int)
df[['timestamp', 'num']]
```

Which gives:

```
         timestamp        num
0   2019-05-01-12:00:00    0
1   2019-05-01-11:00:00    0
2   2019-05-01-10:00:00    3
3   2019-05-01-09:00:00    0
4   2019-05-01-08:00:00    1
5   2019-05-01-07:00:00    1
6   2019-05-01-06:00:00    0
7   2019-05-01-05:00:00    0
8   2019-05-01-04:00:00    0
9   2019-05-01-03:00:00    0
10  2019-05-01-02:00:00    0
11  2019-05-01-01:00:00    0
```